# Post to php script angularJS

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

Below is a my CRUD code for a shopping cart using AngularJS;

```
$scope.items = <?php echo json_encode($item_array); ?>;
$scope.cart = [];
$scope.deleteItem = function(item) {
  var cart = $scope.cart;
  var match = getMatchedCartItem(item);
  if (match.count) {
    cart.splice(cart.indexOf(item), 1);
    return;
  }
}

$scope.addItem = function(item) {
  var match = getMatchedCartItem(item);
  if (match) {
    match.count += 1;
    return;
  }
  var itemToAdd = angular.copy(item);
  itemToAdd.count = 1;
  $scope.cart.push(itemToAdd);
}

$scope.incQty = function(item) {
  var match = getMatchedCartItem(item);
  if (match) {
    match.count += 1;
    return;
  }
}

$scope.decQty = function(item) {
  var cart = $scope.cart;
  var match = getMatchedCartItem(item);
  if (match.count > 1) {
    match.count -= 1;
    return;
  }
  cart.splice(cart.indexOf(item), 1);
}

$scope.subTotal = function() {
  var subtotal = 0;
  for (var i = 0, max = $scope.cart.length; i < max; i++) {
    subtotal += $scope.cart[i].price * $scope.cart[i].count;
  }
  $scope.subtotal = subtotal;
}

$scope.calcTotal = function() {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0, max = $scope.cart.length; i < max; i++) {
    total += $scope.cart[i].price * $scope.cart[i].count;
  }
  $scope.total = total + $scope.qwickCharge;
}
```

With the above, I'm saving everything using localStorage and cookies.
So a user can return and I just retrieve their cart from localStorage or cookies.
Obviously that is not a secure way of doing things.
What I want to be able to do is persist the cart to MySQL DB and reference it using a `$_COOKIE` or `$_SESSION`.

Can anyone assist me with how to embed angular `$http` to post to my `.php` script server side. I don't need the php code. Just the AngularJS code so as part of $scope.deleteItem for example I post to my db the item deleted and I can handle deleting it from my cart table.

**FYI: item is an array containing name,qty,price etc**